# how can i delete an item from listview and also database

Tags: android, xml, database

this is ma program.in this program on delete button there didnt perform onclick listener please solve this problem or how can i get the id of an particular item.

```
    delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
    delete.setOnClickListener(this);
    if(v.equals(delete))
    { 
        new AlertDialog.Builder(ShareFolioEditActivity.this) 
         .setTitle("Delete")
     .setMessage("Are you sure ??? ")
             .setNeutralButton("no",null)
             .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
     delete();                
    }
})      .show();

    }
}

public void delete()
{  
   db.delete("sharelist", "_id="+ID, null);
   Toast.makeText(this, "row deleted"+ID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   Bundle b=null;
   onCreate(b);
}
```

this is my xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10sp">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/category"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text=""
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/catagory"
 />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

please tell me solution

Thanks

Comment: You are using  delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete); and public void delete(). function and variable name which reads button is same. First change them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `this` as the `onClick` listener for a button, you must also implement the `onClick` method within your activity. The code that runs your dialog and performs the delete action will never be called in your case.

Refactor the code to something like:

```
    delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
    delete.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(v.equals(delete))
    { 
        new AlertDialog.Builder(ShareFolioEditActivity.this) 
            .setTitle("Delete")
            .setMessage("Are you sure ??? ")
            .setNeutralButton("no",null)
            .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    delete();                
            }}).show();
    }
}

public void delete()
{  
    db.delete("sharelist", "_id="+ID, null);
    Toast.makeText(this, "row deleted"+ID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Bundle b=null;
    onCreate(b);
}
```

Note: I've not checked this code, it might not compile, but it gives you an idea.