# Deleting items in a listView and database

Tags: android, listview, delete-row

I am trying to delete objects in a listView and database at the same time after you have clicked the item in the listView. I'm tying to make it open an alert dialog before deleting the item. I have read many other stack overflow questions about this such as :

[how can i delete an item from listview and also database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447766/how-can-i-delete-an-item-from-listview-and-also-database)

[delete a specific item from listview stored in database in android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102984/delete-a-specific-item-from-listview-stored-in-database-in-android-application)

[Delete item from database -  ListView - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684511/delete-item-from-database-listview-android)

And many others...none of them I find very helpful. Any suggestions?

**Main_Activity:**

```
public class New_Recipe extends AppCompatActivity {

Button add, done;
EditText Recipe_Name, Recipe_Item, Recipe_Steps;
String search;
WebView webView;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
ListView ItemsList;
Context context = this;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
Cursor cursor;
RecipeListAdapter listAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new__recipe);
    setTitle("New Recipe");
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Recipe_Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Recipe_Item = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Recipe_Steps = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    ItemsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listAdapter = new RecipeListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.recipe_textview);
    context = this;
    AddData();



}
//When the add button is pressed
public void AddData() {
  add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          String item = Recipe_Item.getText().toString();

          databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
          sqLiteDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

          databaseHelper.addItems(item, sqLiteDatabase);

          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          databaseHelper.close();

          ItemsList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

          databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
          sqLiteDatabase = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

          cursor = databaseHelper.getItems(sqLiteDatabase);

          if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
              do {

                  String items;

                  items = cursor.getString(0);

                  RecipeDataProvider dataProvider = new RecipeDataProvider(items);

                  listAdapter.add(dataProvider);

              } while (cursor.moveToNext());
          }
      }

  });

}







public void onSearch(View v) {
    search = "Recipes";
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + search);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new__recipe, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**DatabaseHelper class:**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Recipes.db";
public static final String CREATE_QUERRY = "create table " + RecipeContract.RecipeEntry.TABLE_NAME + "( _ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NAME text, ITEMS text, STEPS text)";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    Log.d("Recipe Database", "Database should be made!");
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERRY);
    Log.d("Recipe Database", "Table should be made!");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void addItems(String items, SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(RecipeContract.RecipeEntry.COL2,items);

    db.insert(RecipeContract.RecipeEntry.TABLE_NAME,null,values);

    Log.e("Recipe Database","Item should be added to the table!");

}
public Cursor getItems(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    Cursor cursor;
    String[] projections = {RecipeContract.RecipeEntry.COL2};

cursor = db.query(RecipeContract.RecipeEntry.TABLE_NAME,projections,null,null,null,null,null);

    return cursor;
}
```

**ListViewAdapter:**

```
public class RecipeListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

List list = new ArrayList();

public RecipeListAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}

static class LayoutHandler
{
    TextView ITEM;
}


@Override
public void add(Object object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return super.getCount();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return super.getItem(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;

    LayoutHandler layoutHandler;


    if (row == null)
    {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recipe_textview,parent,false);

        layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();

        layoutHandler.ITEM = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx_items);

        row.setTag(layoutHandler);

    } else {

        layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) row.getTag();
    }

    RecipeDataProvider dataProvider = (RecipeDataProvider) this.getItem(position);
    layoutHandler.ITEM.setText(dataProvider.getItems().toString());

    return row;
}
```

**EDIT:** my updated Main_Activity class

```
public class New_Recipe extends AppCompatActivity {

Button add, done;
EditText Recipe_Name, Recipe_Item, Recipe_Steps;
String search;
WebView webView;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
ListView ItemsList;
Context context = this;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
Cursor cursor;
RecipeListAdapter listAdapter;
List<New_Recipe> list = new ArrayList<>();
private int id;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new__recipe);
    setTitle("New Recipe");
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Recipe_Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Recipe_Item = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Recipe_Steps = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    ItemsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listAdapter = new RecipeListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.recipe_textview);
    context = this;

    AddData();


    ItemsList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Object getSelectedItem = list.get(position);

            databaseHelper.deleteItem(getSelectedItem);
            listAdapter.deleteitem(getSelectedItem);

            return true;
        }
    });



}

public New_Recipe(){

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: If you make your database data available via a ContentProvider, and populate your ListView from it (via an adapter) then when you delete a row in your database, your ListView should automatically update. It's a bit more work to create a Content Provider, but you may find its worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method for deleting a row from DatabaseHelper class :

```
public void deleteItem(Object item) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(item.getId())});
    db.close();
}
```

And then you need also one method for deleting object from adapter :

```
public void deleteItem(Object item) {
    listArray.remove(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now you can call all this method in activity like this :

Let's say that you want to delete all this by clicking long on list item :

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int pos, long id) {
            Object getSelectedItem = arrayList.get(pos);

            dataBaseHelper.deleteItem(getSelectedItem);
            adapter.deleteItem(getSelectedItem);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

**UPDATED:**

You need before you try to call method `getId()` to create that method in your class. So you need to create get and setter methods in your class, something like this:

**STEP BY STEP:**

1. Change your class `New_Recipe` to `MainActivity`. If you are getting an error, just highlight that error and there you will see "rename file".

   2. Create a new class outside your main class and call it `NewRecipe`:

      `public class NewRecipe {`

      `private int id;`

      `private String title;`

      `public NewRecipe() {`
       `// empty constructor`
       `}`

      `public int getId() {`
      `return id;`
      `}`

      `public void setId(int id) {`
      `this.id = id;`
      `}` 
      `}`

And now you can do everything i have explained earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When I try to type `(item.getId())});`  it only gives me the option of typing `(item.getClass())});` . Is the arrayList in `arrayList.get(pos);` the same one as in `listArray.remove(item)` ? If so how to you get to use the arrayList variable in a different class? I'm quite new to this...

Comment: It still won't let do `(item.getId))});` does this have something to do with where I am creating the getter and setter methods?

Comment: Yes ok, I have updated my Main_Activity in the question.

Comment: Okay, first of all you are doing here some bad practice and we will correct that. I will update my answer and you follow me what i'm doing step by step for achieving your goal.

Comment: The app runs now although i'm getting a logcat error reading `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0` when I long-click the list view.

Comment: Add this to your `onLongItemClickListener()` method:

Comment: `if (arrayList.size == 0) { System.out.printlin("the list is empty)"} else { Object getSelectedItem = arrayList.get(pos);`

Comment: `dataBaseHelper.deleteItem(getSelectedItem);
            adapter.deleteItem(getSelectedItem);

            return true;`

Comment: No , that didn't help... Are you working with Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, and send me log error message you are getting.

Comment: In `onItemLongClickListener()``you should pass your object of class NewRecipe and second you should do, as i explained in answer, change the name of your activity class to MainActivity and create a new class outside the MainActivity

Comment: Change `Object getSelectedItem = list.get(position);` to `NewRecipe newRecipe = list.get(position);`

Answer (score 0):

You need a function `delete`in DatabaseHelper class

```
public boolean delete(long rowId) {
      return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
```

You need a function in the Activity `deleteItem`() similar to `addItems()`

```
public void deleteItem(){

//Based on some logic,find the rowID of the table which needs to be deleted and call delete function of DatabaseHelper class.
}
```

Similarily in your ListViewAdapter, you need to define a method delete

```
public void delete(Object object) {
    list.remove(object);
    //To update the ListView in Android
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```